# Image Map with Icons Placed in Hotspots

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

So, my project, in a nutshell, allows users to view an ImageMap with predefined hotspots that represent the locations of printers around the office. When they hover over these hotspots, I will add a tooltip telling them the name of the printer and give them the ability to install the printer drivers remotely.

My question would be: is it possible to add an icon (such as a small printer that would be the same for each hotspot) in the locations of the hotspots using jquery or some other method? I'm aware that you can't add a CssClass to hotspots (which is kind of a bummer), but is there a way to force this, or use a plugin like ImageMapster to make it so that the icons are constantly there in order to signify where the printers are?

Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a hotspot, why don't you just use a relatively positioned div with absolutely positioned icons? The functionality is basically the same apart from the fact that the dimensions of the icons will need to be square. i.e. with a set width/height; you can't draw circles or polygons like you can in a hotspot.

This will give you full control over where things are positioned and you can have different CSS classes for each hot spot.

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't really think about something like that. In the end, my reasoning for the hotspots was really that I could do the placing of the images in jquery (my new favorite thing to use these days). But I suppose manually positioning the icons with margins and such would work as well.

Comment: Yeah, you can still use jQuery if you need to calculate the coordinates. Don't use margins. Use `position: absolute` along with `top` / `left` / `bottom` / `right` coordinates.